# Insert database entries in different format

Tags: mysql

I have to fill entries in a new database. The old schema looked like following:

```
+------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| trainee_id             | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date                   | date     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| duration               | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| documentationReference | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| educationDepartment    | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| completedtasks         | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| yearOfTraining         | int(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So now my insert statements looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `report_completedtask`
      VALUES (997,
              3,
             '2015-01-23',
             8,
             NULL,
             'Netzwerk und Sicherheit',
             'Berufsschule',
             1);
```

But since my new schema looks like this:

```
+----------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| trainee_id           | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| task                 | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date                 | date     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| year_of_training     | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| duration             | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| documentation        | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| education_department | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I would need the following insert statement structure:

```
INSERT INTO `report_completedtask`
     VALUES (997,
             3,
             'Netzwerk und Sicherheit',
             '2015-01-23',
             1,
             8,
             NULL,
             'Berufsschule');
```

Here is the **real problem**: I have a **huge file** with the old entries which has more than 1000 lines. Is there any way I can rearrange them all for the new schema and alter the file?

Edit: I took dan08's approach now and combined it with a simple vi command:

```
:%s/VALUES/(id,trainee_id,date,duration,documentation,education_department,task,year_of_training) VALUES/g
```

Sometimes it is just too simple :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you know you can specify the columns to insert into. Example

```
INSERT INTO my_table (col_a, col_c, col_b) VALUES ('a', 'c', 'b');
```

So I think all you need to do is explicitly specify the columns to insert into. And they can be in any order, regardless of their order in the table.

You can also INSERT multiple rows at once like so:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (col_a, col_c, col_b) VALUES 
  ('a', 'c', 'b'), 
  ('b', 'c', 'a'), 
  ... , 
  ('b', 'a', 'c');
```

Comment: But how can I make it work so I don't have to do this manually for more than 1000 lines of insert statements?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your SGBD but with **oracle** you can do something like it :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
FROM tbl_temp1
WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

In your case I recommend you to write a block PL/SQLif your SGBD manage it.

Other possibility if you don't want bother with code you can use ***talend*** to read your file and insert your data !